# Search box does not allow users to press "Enter"

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search

I have a Search Server 2010 installation with pretty much the default installation and only minimal customization. Unfortunately on my search page, the search box does not allow users to press "Enter" to submit their search but does work if they press the magnifying glass button. This is not consistent over all browsers, Chrome seems to work but IE doesn't.

I have seen some similar questions which talk about editing javascript but I'm not sure where this would actually be done. If that is the resolution please could you advise how to get to the backend code. I have only needed to amend things in Central Administration prior to now.